# How to send error message from node express to retrofit on android

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit

I have a nodes server, and on my android device I'm using retrofit to talk to my API.

if I do a regular/succesfull response from server, `res.json(User)` or `res.send("message")`, I get the the response body on the android correctly.

```
public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
    //response contains a body or message
}
```

HOWEVER, if I want to send an error, and use

```
res.status(500).json({"msg":"user not found");
```

or

```
res.status(500).send("user not found")
```

inside of my retrofit callback, I get a on success call back with the correct status code, in this case 500, but the error message I'm trying to send is not passed to me.

It seems that since the http response status was an error status, retrofit just ignores the response body/contents.

How can I send an error status 500, but also send data with it to retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

I always use this approach:

```
res.send({status:200, "msg":"user not found"});
```

Comment: I figured I can do that, but the problem is our iOS app is depending on the current method, and we wanna try not to change it.